# problems installing driver for REALTEK 8812BU - AC1200M

Tags: ubuntu-drivers

it came with the driver on the CD, as my computer has no reader, I put it on another computer and copied it to a USB stick, I couldn't use the automatic installer and tried to install it manually, went into the folder and ran the 'make' command and the following error:

```
make ARCH=x86_64 CROSS_COMPILE= -C /lib/modules/4.15.0-72-generic/build M=/home/mariana/Downloads/rtl88x2bu-driver-master  modules
make[1]: Entering directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-4.15.0-72-generic'
  CC [M]  /home/mariana/Downloads/rtl88x2bu-driver-master/os_dep/linux/os_intfs.o
/home/mariana/Downloads/rtl88x2bu-driver-master/os_dep/linux/os_intfs.c:1433:22: error: initialization from incompatible pointer type [-Werror=incompatible-pointer-types]
  .ndo_select_queue = rtw_select_queue,
                      ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/home/mariana/Downloads/rtl88x2bu-driver-master/os_dep/linux/os_intfs.c:1433:22: note: (near initialization for ‘rtw_netdev_ops.ndo_select_queue’)
cc1: some warnings being treated as errors
scripts/Makefile.build:330: recipe for target '/home/mariana/Downloads/rtl88x2bu-driver-master/os_dep/linux/os_intfs.o' failed
make[2]: *** [/home/mariana/Downloads/rtl88x2bu-driver-master/os_dep/linux/os_intfs.o] Error 1
Makefile:1577: recipe for target '_module_/home/mariana/Downloads/rtl88x2bu-driver-master' failed
make[1]: *** [_module_/home/mariana/Downloads/rtl88x2bu-driver-master] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-4.15.0-72-generic'
Makefile:1986: recipe for target 'modules' failed
make: *** [modules] Error 2
```

i use ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS
kernel 4.15.0-72-generic

Comment: The driver in the dongle is incompatible with new kernels.